# Poisson distrubution proof question.

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I was reading over the proof for the Poisson distribution and came across this sentence:
 "But since $$\left[1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right]^n\rightarrow e^{-\lambda}$$ as $$n\rightarrow\infty$$, ..."
Can someone explain how they have arrived at that result and why the above term doesn't simply become $$1^n=1$$? By the way $$\lambda=np$$ where p is the probability and n is the number of data points.

Comment: Recall "indeterminate forms" from the calculus. In general, if we know that $f(n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, we cannot say anything about what happens to $(1+f(n))^n$ as $n\to\infty$.  But we do know that the limit of $(1+x/n)^n$ is $e^x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact $$
  \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x
$$
is very well known (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) for example). It's sometimes even taken to be the *definition* of $e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

fgp's answer that the limit *can* be taken as the definition of $e^x$ is totally right, but most often we define $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$$

Now let us calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e$$

We make the substitution $t=n/x$

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^t\right)^x = e^x$$

Comment: This looks circular - how do you *define* exponentiation for non-rational exponents, without resorting to $e^x$? You might say that you imagine $x$ to be rational, in which case you can define $x^{\frac{p}{q}} := \sqrt[q]{x^p}$. This removes the circularity, but you'll now need to first show that $x^r$ is continuous in $x$ so that you may swap the limit and the exponentation.

Comment: @fgp yes I was referring to $x^y$ being continuous. Proving that is left as an exercise. In the case of *defining* this to be $e^x$ you also need to show things like $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^n = \left[\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^n\right]^2$$. But that follows from continuity as well.

Comment: Still, how do you get around the circularity? You need to *define* $x^y$ before you can prove it's continuity. So what your approach comes down to is to define exponentation for rational exponents, proving it continuous as a function $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$, then extending that to $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, the using *that* to define $e^x$. It seems way simpler to just *define* $e^x$ via the limit, proving it to be continuous and injective, defining $\log x$ as its inverse, and defining $x^y$ as $e^{y\log x}$.

Comment: @fgp seems simpler yes, at the end, since both methods work, it comes down to whatever "floats your boat"